# Recover .git folder from an older commit on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I usually use git from the GUI in my IDE, but I wanted to do something through the command line. However, this messed up the local `.git` repository that I had for my project, and now I am unable to commit and push files to my remote repository on GitHub. My project files are still intact and safe, it's only the `.git` repo that has been messed up.

As my files are still safe, is there a way to recover the repository as it was during an older commit. I have tried downloading the code as it was during an older commit from GitHub, but the `.git` files is not included. Is is possible to download the repository from GitHub directly.

There were several months of work on my repo, so I really do not want to lose that history. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Can you include the error log from trying to commit or push files? Maybe we can solve the problem by fixing `.git`.

Comment: This is what it's saying (from CLion):

0 file committed, 3 files failed to commit: commit message invalid object 100644 0a743e97ec9a19a4522c508d53cfcf500207500d for 'file/path.cpp' invalid object 100644 0a743e97ec9a19a4522c508d53cfcf500207500d for 'file/path.cpp' Error building trees

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38603911/11688567

Comment: did you by any chance run your cli actions as root (linux) or from an elevated privileges console (windows) ? can you check the access rights on files within your `.git/` directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be considering a very manual/hacky way of restoring it but you have several options:

1. Git clone the repo from GitHub into a new folder. Delete `.git` in the old folder and `cp -r .git` from the new folder to the old one. You can then commit the new files as desired.
   **Note**: By using this method, you lose all your commits, that have not been pushed to github and are only present in the local `git` repository.
2. Based on your error message in the commends `Error Building Trees` `Commit Message Invalid Object...`, you can consult this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448326/git-commit-stopped-working-error-building-trees) facing the same problem as yourself.

Comment: I tried option 1 and it worked. Thanks for the answer!